# $0$s in the binary expansion of $\sqrt 2$

Tags: binary, decimal-expansion

Consider the decimal expansion of  $ \sqrt 2$ in base $2$: $ \sqrt 2=1+\displaystyle \sum_{k\ge1} r_k 2^{-k},  r_k=0, 1. $
Let us prove the following fact: for every $n\ge1$, there is at least $n\le k\le 2n$ s.t $r_k=1.$

(Note that the proof is inspired from an existing one regarding $\sqrt 3$, but I lost the link}).

Assume that $r_k=0 $ for $ k=n,n+1,..,2n$. Then $2^{n-1} \sqrt 2=m+\epsilon, $ where $m\in\mathbf{N}$ and $0<\epsilon \le 2^{-n-1}$. It follows that
$
2^{2n-1}=m^2+2 m \epsilon+\epsilon^2.$
Moreover, we have $m< 2^{n-1} \sqrt 2,$ thus
$0<2 m \epsilon+\epsilon^2< 2^{-1}\sqrt 2 +    2^{-2n-2}<1.
$ Hence  $2^{2n-1}=m^2$ which is impossible.

I wonder if the following result is also true:  for every $n\ge1$ large enough, there is at least $n\le k\le 2n$ s.t $r_k=0.$

Comment: Wouldn't a similar proof work, with $2^{n-1}\sqrt 2=m+1-\varepsilon$ or something like that?

Comment: I think this will work. Thanks